# How to get Date object from Knockout observable of Date type

Tags: javascript, jquery, datetime, knockout.js, datepicker

I am using [MakerStudios/ko-calendar](https://github.com/MakerStudios/ko-calendar) for binding DateTime to Input box.

I have two HTML input boxes which are date-binded to two variables namely START_DATE and END_DATE.

**HTML**

```
Start Date:<input data-bind="value: START_DATE.value, calendar:START_DATE " readonly>
End Date:<input data-bind="value: END_DATE.value, calendar:END_DATE " readonly>
```

**ViewModel**

```
 var ViewModel = function () {
                var self = this;
                self.START_DATE = {
                    value: ko.observable(),
                    current: new Date(),
                    min: new Date()
                };

                self.END_DATE = {
                    value: ko.observable(),
                    min:new Date(),              // should be set to the START_DATE's Date Value
                    autoclose: false
                };
}
```

The Default Option 'min' for END_DATE is of Date() Type and I want to set 'min' to START_DATE's Date value, so that the END_DATE should always be greater than START_DATE.

I have tried `min:self.START_DATE.value(),` but it doesn't work as `self.START_DATE.value()` is an observable variable not a Date Type variable.

Then I got struck.

So I want to know is there any way to get the Date value from knockout Observable Variable (that is in my case is `self.START_DATE.value()`).

Comment: help me understand is this what you looking for http://jsfiddle.net/supercool/LkqTU/26744/

Comment: @supercool : I want to set 'min' of END_DATE to self.START_DATE.value() just as you did, but this is not possible directly as 'min' is DATE type variable where as 'self.START_DATE.value()' is not Date Type variable.  So I need to extract the Date from self.START_DATE.value() into some DATE TYPE variable and then assign it to the 'min' of END_DATE.

Comment: `self.START_DATE.current` is of type Date Object only . for checking try `typeof(new Date())` & `new typeof(//your observable)` both having `Date` instance methods i.e `getDate` etc

Comment: @supercool: I get 'getDate' method with new Date() but my observable (i.e self.START_DATE.value() )does not give me any such method.                                        .               see this https://jsfiddle.net/himanshudhiman/5vLm0xfL/....

Comment: that's because initially observable is not set with any value check this https://jsfiddle.net/supercool/5vLm0xfL/1/ . PS : don't compare two dates via `==` in js wont result you true .

Comment: @supercool: Thanks.. I was wrong on the part that both are not of same Date Type Object as i hadn't initialized my self.START_DATE.value() with a new Date(). But this plugin also doesn't allow you to reinitialize 'min' property.. check this https://jsfiddle.net/5vLm0xfL/2/

Comment: make `min` as observable and you will see changes allowed check here https://jsfiddle.net/supercool/5vLm0xfL/4/ .

Comment: @supercool: Sir when i make 'min' as observable with  MakerStudios/ko-calendar included as plugin then i get errors and my code breaks.... but when i remove this plugin and make 'min' as observable it works.... Basically this particular Plugin does not allow you to make 'min' as observable.

Comment: is there any chance you can give me a `fiddle` with the plugin your are taking and your code which is breaking let me try to fix it .

Comment: @supercool: yea Sure...  http://jsfiddle.net/himanshudhiman/x1u2wcLm/

Comment: @supercool: Would you please see my new problem ....http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32632265/how-to-masked-an-input-text-box-which-is-data-binded-to-knockout-computed-variab

Comment: again a basic mistake check here let me know http://jsfiddle.net/supercool/x1u2wcLm/2/

Comment: @supercool: Again my bad for doing that mistake...but i am still trapped as i am unable to get what i want... i want to set 'min' dynamically ... check out this fiddler ....http://jsfiddle.net/himanshudhiman/bvmq2ny1/ my doubt is commented in html

Comment: ooh you need to use custom binding handlers to configure your dynamic options there .