# How to masked an input text box which is data-bound to Knockout computed variable

Tags: jquery, html, knockout.js, maskedinput, computed-observable

I am using jquery [MASKED INPUT PLUGIN](http://digitalbush.com/projects/masked-input-plugin/) for masking my input boxes which are data-binded to knockout variables.
I have problem in masking if the knockout variable is Computed Variable.

Here is the Fiddler Link https://jsfiddle.net/himanshudhiman/2h1f18qo/5/

I am able to mask input boxes of observable array. 
But I don't get masking option for the input box of Computed Variable(i.e here in my code is "self.SelectById()").

**ViewModel**

```
function KeyValuePairOfIdAndName(Name, ID) {
            var self = this;
            self.Name = Name;
            self.ID = ID;
        }

var ViewModel = function () {
    var self = this;
    self.listOfkeyValue = ko.observableArray();
    self.SelectById = ko.computed(function () {
        return ko.utils.arrayFilter(self.listOfkeyValue(), function (Fruit) {
            return Fruit.ID == 1001;
        });
    });
    var count = 1;
    self.CreateNewFruit = function () {

        self.listOfkeyValue.push(new KeyValuePairOfIdAndName("Apple" + count, 999 + count));
        $(".inputboxofEachFruit").mask("9999");
        count = count + 1;

    }

}

$(document).ready(function () {
    var viewModel = new ViewModel();
    ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
    $(".inputboxofEachFruit").mask("9999");
    $(".inputboxofSelectedFruit").mask("9999");
});
```

**HTML**

```
<button data-bind="event: { mousedown: CreateNewFruit }" >Createe Fruit</button>    
<br/>  
Fruits From Observable Array
<div data-bind="foreach: listOfkeyValue" >                            
    <input class = "inputboxofEachFruit" data-bind="value: ID"/>   
</div>
<br/>  
<span style = "color:Red;">Fruits From computed variable</span>
<div data-bind="foreach: SelectById" >                            
    <input class = "inputboxofSelectedFruit" data-bind="value: ID"/>   
</div>
```

I have an idea that, i need to bind dynamically created variables to mask's property and i have done that in "self.CreateNewFruit()" after pushing new element in "self.listOfkeyValue()". But what to do with Computed Variables. How to mask them.

Comment: simple you need to dynamically add `.mask` to dynamically generated elements check here https://jsfiddle.net/supercool/2h1f18qo/7/

Comment: or just set an eventhandler for the textbox change event and mask it there

Comment: @supercool: Thanks.. it worked... Now I add .mask at knockout click binding..

Comment: @ScottSelby: I tried to put click event binding and it worked but for other events binding it does not. I put focusin and tried to alert a message but got nothing..  Fiddler https://jsfiddle.net/himanshudhiman/pnx0du61/1/

Comment: use `$parent` in html to get the event fired

Comment: @supercool: Okay i got it... once i get inside foreach div i lost parent scope.. so i need to mention it...Thanks..

Comment: @supercool: Yea Sure No problem Sir.. :) If you don't mind can i have your email-id..i usually have many silly doubts and need some expertise for rescue. Please drop a link of your email at 23himanshu92@gmail.com. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

one way would be using `trigger` to add `.mask` when ever new element is created

**Code:**

```
$("#cool").on("click", function () {
   $(".one").mask("9999"); //dynamic elements with same class name get's mask
});
 $("#cool").trigger("click");
```

working sample with your code **[here](https://jsfiddle.net/supercool/2h1f18qo/7/)**

other simple way would be under your `ko click` event add `.mask` on class name make sure you maintain same class across mask-able elements like **[here](https://jsfiddle.net/supercool/2h1f18qo/8/)**